# need guidance before revoking my developer certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

When i install a provisioning profile into Xcode,it shows "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain". Checking my login keychain(default), it has the public and private key along with my developer certificate and Apple's intermediate certificate. Also, while building my app in Xcode i got the error "The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain"But the problem is the private key is not linked with the developer certificate, which should be in order to code sign and test the app into my device(acc to the guide).

Is there any way to link the key and certificate?

Or do I delete everything and revoke my certificate?

Please guide me as to what should be done in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved: i revoked the certificate and sent the CertificateSigningRequest to the dev portal again, on installing the profile in Xcode i restarted my Mac, got the cert and installed in the login keychain, again restarted the Mac, and now am able to work my apps in my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall my MAC OS. I have the same problem. maybe not exactly same.

I revoke certificate and do everything over again. just get a new private key. then everything fixed